# Android Bring call in progress to front?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app for universal access, my app works in fullscreen with a custom dialer. So if users press home or back during a phone call I need to give them the opportunity to return the call somehow. (In fact I'm thinking about reopening the call in progress automatically if they leave).

I know how to start a call with a number but I don't know how to open the incall screen during a call, I tried doing an Intent.ACTION_CALL without a number but it initiates a second phone call on top of the other:

```
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

I think this should be doen with an intent or by simply bringing it to front. But I don't know how to do it. How can I reopen a call in progress programatically?

Comment: But i think if calls comes it automatically override others apps screen and comes in front?

Comment: yes, but if the user clicks "back" or "home" during the call he can leave the phone offhook while in other apps. I need some way to bring him back.

Comment: its user who did it, y don't u leave it that way?

Comment: because it's a universal access app and sometimes the users do things accidentally like leaving a conversation in progress and I need some way to bring it back to front. Also the app has a Dialer, the default dialer offers a "Return to call screen" button but since I'm overriding it with mine I need to implement my own "return" button. What is more my app has a fullscreen setting and (since there is no status bar) it's basically impossible to return to the call screen after leaving it  unless I create a button on my app/prevent users from leaving

Comment: ok got it now,  have you tried Intent.ACTION_DIAL ?

Comment: yes I did, ACTION_DIAL always takes you to the dialer, even if there is a call in progress

Comment: ok, let me see if there is other ways to do so. it is most of like hit and try type , :)

Answer (score 6):

if it's still relevant or for other people interested in this:

ACTION_CALL_BUTTON do exactly that.

if the call is in progress, it would bring it to the front, and if it's not, it would
bring the call log.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL_BUTTON

Comment: CyanogenMod 2.3 on HTC Hero - it opens dial and not 'call in progress' screen.

Comment: As of the date of posting this comment, this answer works perfectly. You only need to get rid of the second argument in the original code: `Uri.parse("tel:")`

Comment: Not working on Samsung phones, it always open the dialer even if a call is in progress

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution that seems to work well. I many combinations of Intents and also tried the ACTION_CALL_BUTTON as suggested above but in 4.3 it opens a new dialer and does not take you to the current call in progress. Not sure how this behaves in older sdks. After much research and tries I found this to work well, although it could probably use some optimizing...

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );
if( telephonyManager.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK )
{
    ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);    
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = m.getRunningTasks( 10 );
    for( int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); ++i )
    {
        RunningTaskInfo task = tasks.get( i );
        ComponentName component = task.baseActivity;
        String packageName = component.getPackageName();
        if( packageName.contains( "com.android.phone" ) )
        {
        m.moveTaskToFront( task.id, 0 );
        return;
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need to add the permissions to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"                />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS"            />
```